# Exceptions that can handle strings

Tags: java, exception

I'm looking for kind of exceptions that can handle string input.
What type of exceptions can I use? 
I need exceptions that works on netbeans (coz some don't).
Please help. :)

Comment: why don't you write your own exception class?

Comment: what is the code that you want to handle exception?

Comment: Exceptions that work on Netbeans? Oh my God. Java is Java. Whether you use NetBeans or not to write the code is irrelevant to how Java works. Define "exception that handle string input".

Comment: I still don't know much.
Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java all the built in exception are the child class of Exception. So if you create your own class that has a parent of Exception then you can use it as a new exception.

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

So now all you gotta do is `throw new MyException("blah blah blah");` where necessary.

Comment: You can accept this answer if you think it is the best answer you would get.